# How to create border offset?

Tags: html, css

Hi I was wondering how I can offset a border from a div, like the image: [image]

So the gray border is the same size as the image, only it is offset to the right corner. This is my markup:

```
<figure class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image">
        <figcaption>
            <p>
            Praesent at luctus erat, non finibus justo. 
            <a href="#">share</a>
            </p>
        </figcaption>
</figure><!-- End figure.col-md-10 -->
```

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple with pseudo elements.

Example

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  left: 30px;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Worth noting that most browsers don't support `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes directly on the `img` element. In this case, a wrapper `div` (or other element) is needed to accomplish the effect, as reflected in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `:before` or `:after` pseudo class

```css
figure {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  position: relative;      
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;  
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div class="image">
    <img width="400px" height="250px" src="http://www.moneywehave.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/know-about-money.jpg">
  </div>
  <figcaption>
    <p>
      Praesent at luctus erat, non finibus justo. 
      <a href="#">share</a>
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure><!-- End figure.col-md-10 -->
```

Comment: You forgot `z-index` )

Comment: Why would i need `z-index` for this ?

Comment: Change your border color and you'll understand that)

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with a [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) as well.

Note, this effect is only usable if the page background is a solid color, as the white fill is creating the effect by masking the gray shadow. If the body background was an image or tile, then this effect would not be suitable. Thanks to @Mi-Creativity for pointing that out.

```css
img {width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red;} /*example "image"*/

img {
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 0 0 white, 1em 1em 0 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<img />
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer! )

Comment: Not effective if the element has different background other than straight colors - *like `white`* - it won't work if the background is an image or a pattern

Comment: @Mi-Creativity yes, you're right.. I had not thought about it

Comment: Thanks @Mi-Creativity. Considering the criteria of the original question, I just wanted to provide an alternative to adding additional DOM elements. You're absolutely right about a textured background and I will make a note of it.

Comment: Considering the image shown in the question as well as most webpage designs currently this answer will work just fine since the majority of webpages backgrounds are just solid colors, but Iwas trying to achieve same thing trying to answer this question and I faced this problemso I just wanted to point that the blank space is a solid color "*white*" rather than transparency